# Select identical classes in conditional types

Tags: typescript

The ultimate goal I have is to be able to extract the types of all resolved data for a given Angular component coming from an entire Angular routing configuration. But this is not an Angular specific problem, it's more about TypeScript.

So far I'm having trouble writing a conditional types that "select" a route only if the component is the one I am interested in. I am using `isEqual`, as found in https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest, to compare the component class, but it seems that it returns false whereas I am expecting to return true in that specific case.

Here's what I got, with heavily simplified types from Angular, and the [Playground version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BAzlAvLRyDaBdAbgCgiBLAO2QCcAzAQwGNp4loBvIqLqMO4ACwD8ALigpgVCgHNi3KAzgBbMHHIRKIqABVwEADx1yIAHyzuVVHAA2ANwiaYl2xAAifOsQC+JCtXpNtXT0tYygIAA9kcgATNAAxBHIGYFJVKA45NQB3AAoAOgK6KikUUUMQfABKUS0vElBIWCc7N2A6DHTObhwAawgQUXFJcikoAB8xEEUAI2s8URzKjFDEnvI4LPIvYhIiGkTk1PIoCxRrOwA5CCyAVRQIKkXRNigaUipxC7pFCEGJaSgnk6cgswAQVGOLzeH2AXx+ogA5AjAXU9gcUmlTucIHcHk90lBSNFROQEDMHgRXu9Pt9fmJ-iNAcDzBAwRCCUTRABGABMAGYADRUmFwukIgBScH4xxccAgyM8qP2SQxxyxzgAQnA4D18S9OVBSeSqJSUsArHShgCgRkWWzIYTiVAACwAVgAbEKzRbEQBBKykAK+6J2Sjg1CE44AdVU0QeVkM0QVqIYCZQaAACkV1MBgqFbVxou4AIQ1FNptC4qgAYSUKjUlDCkXUsSgWYslD0cSoSn9VhYyBQegaEDgNBO2FQXt0Y6gVdrylUOeMxgLr21i2Zci4AlIKDyRbaeQQ9xNUAA9OeoABJJuQZJQXdoYBwKDTaAAAxHs-Vl2uVfGR8QAgFRx1-HFTw-Lpt0ffg9wPdw8lmHVKUvG87wgB8n0fV96FIKxoMBIhvCIVM6HTKAtR1Bd6xzJsolbdscy7HtFD7AdUGHGcwMnFBp0gWcqJ6Gil0oFc13XOBNwk7gnwQo8TwpC8r1vCJ72AWC9xw146Hwwi5Dkw86CQ7UelQlSMKwuDn1fd8oC-biTmaCAhKguRvBIhRyHECdWC5UQOI6NdeAERFFKoc9sgRAVCIURcG2AUR5zrUTgBikFnOefTuHC0RwKuW5T3S7hPBioEUD4Pc3gjDidi8nye1YHkAsnILCJC-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):

```
type Routes = Route[];

interface Route {
    path?: string;
    component?: Type<any>;
    resolve?: ResolveData;
}

interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

type ResolveData = {
    [key: string | symbol]: () => unknown;
};



function resolveNewUser(): { firstName: string } {
    return { firstName: '' };
}

function resolveUser(): { id: number; firstName: string } {
    return { id: 123, firstName: 'John Doe' };
}

function resolveBook(): { id: number; title: string } {
    return { id: 456, title: 'Alice Adventures in Wonderland' };
}

class Parent<T> {
    data!: T;
}

class UserComponent extends Parent<FromAllRoutes<typeof routes, typeof UserComponent>>{
    foo() {
        this.data.user; // I expect this to be `typeof resolveNewUser | tyepof resolveUser`
        this.data.book; // I expect this to fail
    }
}

class BookComponent extends Parent<FromAllRoutes<typeof routes, typeof BookComponent>>{
     foo() {
        this.data.user; // I expect this to fail
        this.data.book; // I expect this to be `typeof resolveBook`
    }
}

const route1: Route = {
    path: 'user/new',
    component: UserComponent,
    resolve: {
        user: resolveNewUser,
    },
} satisfies Route;

const route2: Route = {
    path: 'user/:userId',
    component: UserComponent,
    resolve: {
        user: resolveUser,
    },
};

const route3: Route = {
    path: 'book',
    component: BookComponent,
    resolve: {
        book: resolveBook,
    },
};

const routes: Routes = [
    route1,
    route2,
    route3,
];

type IsEqual<A, B> =
    (<G>() => G extends A ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<G>() => G extends B ? 1 : 2)
    ? true
    : false;

// This might be wrong, but I am already stuck here
type ExtractRouteData<R extends Route, C extends Type<any>> = IsEqual<C, R['component']> extends true ? R extends { resolve?: infer MyResolvedData } ? MyResolvedData : 'should never happen' : 'different types';

type FromAllRoutes<...> = ...ExtractRouteData... // how do I complete this ?
```

`UserComponent.foo()` should be able to access `this.data.user` because `user` is a key defined in `route1` and also in `route2`, albeit with different type. But `book` should not be defined for that component, because the key is only defined in `route3` which is declared for BookComponent.

I've read the long discussion in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024, but I am still not sure that comparing classes, and not merely types, to be **identical**, and not merely equivalent, is supposed to be supported by the `IsEqual` workaround.

Any suggestion on how to go forward ?

Comment: I'm very confused by the level of circularity in your definitions here, what `IsEqual<>` is supposed to achieve, and why identity vs structural compatibility matters.  If I take your example code I can tease it apart to be non-circular like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGXdJw) and things seem fine, but maybe I'm missing the point.  Could you see if that works for you? If so I could write up an answer. If not, could you [edit] to make clear what doesn't work about that?

Comment: @jcalz, `IsEqual<>` is meant to compare two class that are *identical*, and not merely *compatible*, because two different components may happens to have the same type structure but requires entirely different resolved data to work properly. So I need to "select" only the routes that concerns exactly *this* component.

Comment: @jcalz, Your suggested solution would work, but has some limitations. It requires a bit more boilerplates (must have resolvers as a separate variables). But most importantly you must list all resolvers in the component class. And it is easy to forget that a component is used in differents routes and may receive different resolved data. In fact you did this mistake. You wrote `UserComponent extends Parent<typeof newUserResolver>`, but it should have been `UserComponent extends Parent<typeof newUserResolver | typeof resolveUser>`. This is exactly what I would love to avoid, if possible...

Comment: I don't see how I made a mistake, given that your example code only had `typeof route1` and not `typeof route1 | typeof route2`; I set up the code exactly as yours, as far as I know.  Can you make sure your code expresses what you want, and [edit] if it does not?  ...  I don't see how to fix the boilerplate issue, or how it's worse than your version.  Maybe I can work on a factory function that produces your classes programmatically from some config.  I'm primarily on mobile for the next few days so it might not be until next week.

Comment: My bad, your code was indeed correct but it did not really fulfilled my goal, because my goal was not clearly explained. I edited the question. Hopefully it is now clearer that the final result I want it to extract resolved data for a **specific component from all routes** at once, so writing something like `class UserComponent extends Parent<FromAllRoutes<typeof routes, typeof UserComponent>>`

Comment: If I were trying to do that I'd be using a factory function [perhaps like this](https://tsplay.dev/Wvy14m) to prevent the vicious circularity.  Note that at no point am I trying to "select identical classes" in the type system. If you find yourself needing to distinguish two things that have identical structure you should consider whether or not this is a *runtime* distinction or an actual *type* distinction.  (e.g., both `x` and `y` might be of type `string`, but `x !== y` would be a runtime way to tell them apart, much easier than trying to force the distinction in the *type system*).

Comment: (see prev comment) Does that fully address the question now? If so I'll write it up as an answer.  If not, if I'm missing something small let me know, otherwise maybe I should disengage if I'm not getting it after this much discussion.  Either way is fine with me.  Tell me how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: Factory function is something I didn't think of at all. Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I omitted a crucial detail, a route can have child routes, `interface Route { children?: Route[] }`. I think this make `makeRoutes()` impractical because we cannot very well construct a relatively complex tree from simple arrays of routes. I suppose the best compromise it still your first suggestion, where we explicitly list all resolvers in the component. There is a big risk of duplication issues, but at least we get typed resolved data in the component and support for a tree of routes.

Comment: I still feel that we should be able to express what I want in TypeScript, and it's either a shortcoming of the language itself or a shortcoming of my knowledge of the language.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is due to the fact that TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal. This means that two types are considered the same if they have the same structure, regardless of their names or where they were declared. This is why directly comparing classes or types using conditional types can be tricky.

However, you can achieve your goal by leveraging TypeScript's type system. Here's a solution that should work for your use case:

***UPDATED SOLUTION 8/23/23***

First, let's define a helper type ExtractRouteData that extracts the resolved data for a given component from a route:

```
type ExtractRouteData<R extends Route, C> = R extends { component: C; resolve?: infer Data } ? Data : never;
```

Next, let's define the FromAllRoutes type that iterates over all routes and accumulates the resolved data for the given component:

```
type FromAllRoutes<Routes extends Route[], C> = Routes extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
    ? ExtractRouteData<First extends Route ? First : never, C> & FromAllRoutes<Rest extends Route[] ? Rest : never, C>
    : {};
```

Now, you can use the FromAllRoutes type to get the resolved data for any component:

```
class UserComponent extends Parent<FromAllRoutes<typeof routes, typeof UserComponent>> {
    foo() {
        this.data.user;        // This should work
        // this.data.nonexisting; // This should fail
    }
}
```

Here's the complete solution:

```
type Routes = Route[];

interface Route {
    path?: string;
    component?: Type<any>;
    resolve?: ResolveData;
}

interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

type ResolveData = {
    [key: string | symbol]: () => unknown;
};

// ... (your functions and classes here)

type ExtractRouteData<R extends Route, C> = R extends { component: C; resolve?: infer Data } ? Data : never;

type FromAllRoutes<Routes extends Route[], C> = Routes extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
    ? ExtractRouteData<First extends Route ? First : never, C> & FromAllRoutes<Rest extends Route[] ? Rest : never, C>
    : {};

class UserComponent extends Parent<FromAllRoutes<typeof routes, typeof UserComponent>> {
    foo() {
        this.data.user;        // This should work now
        // this.data.nonexisting; // This should still fail
    }
}
```

This solution leverages TypeScript's powerful conditional and mapped types to extract and accumulate the resolved data for a given component from all routes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this solution produces two errors in [the playground](https://t.ly/qPjuo).

First: `Type 'Rest' does not satisfy the constraint 'Route[]'.`.

And second, more importantly: `Property 'user' does not exist on type '{}'` showing that resolved data are not typed correctly.

I don't get why TypeScript cannot infer that `Rest` can only be `Route` and instead treat it as unknown ?

Comment: Type 'Rest' does not satisfy the constraint 'Route[]'.: This error arises because TypeScript cannot guarantee that Rest will always be an array of Route objects. To fix this, we can add a type assertion.

Property 'user' does not exist on type '{}': This error indicates that the type of this.data is being inferred as an empty object {}. This is likely because the recursive type FromAllRoutes is terminating prematurely, resulting in an empty type. I'll update the solution.

Comment: This updated version, https://t.ly/3Ya1p, shows that Rest was fixed, thanks. But we still get `Property 'user' does not exist on type '{}'.`, meaning that our class comparison does not seem to work... ?